# Java agent not forwarding traces to appneta tracelytics/traceview

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jetty, trace

I'm trying to configure Appneta traceview on one of my internal hosts.

The instructions say to put a "-javaagent:/blah/de/traceview.jar" argument when I launch tomcat or jetty.  However, it just is not happening.

I have a tracer on Apache (httpd) on the same host and it's coming through loud and clear.

The logs don't seem to show any communication from the agent.  It makes me crazy!

Comment: What kind of app is running inside Tomcat/Jetty? If it's some non HTTP service (doesn't inherit from servlet somewhere) you may need to initiate traces manually via the API. That agent only automatically instruments web apps by default.

Comment: Oh!  No - many are NOT subclasses of servlet.

Also, I did not have 'trace all' in the config file.  Is there any other way to inject instrumentation?

Comment: Yeah there's an API you can use to manually control the starting and stopping of traces for non HTTP request cycles you want visibility into (eg. queue consumers, report generation, etc). Everything servlet should be traced automatically though.